# Spring ConversionService for linked list

Tags: java, spring

I would like to do a converter that gets a list and returns a list but i cant seem to understand how to call that converter. (it might be some syntax i don't fully understand)

deceleration of spring converter factory:

> ```
>  <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
>     <property name="converters">
>         <list>
>             <bean class="com.X.Y.Z.converters.MyCustomListConverter"/>
>         </list>
>     </property>
> </bean>
> ```

I have my converter

```
public class MyCustomListConverter implements Converter<List<MyClass1>, List<MyClass2>>
```

I am trying to call it but with out luck.

I have tried this (which compiles but doesnt call the converter)

```
conversionService.convert(myObjects1, LinkedList.class);
```

And some other tries that don't even compile.

Thanks

Comment: what has that to do with spring?

Comment: You have not shown us enough code to check what the issue is.

Comment: when i call the convert with LinkedList.class it does not reference the type List<MyClass2>. so how to i call the converter with expected class of List<MyClass2>?

Comment: What is myObjects1? What is the result you get back from the ConversionService? Does it throw a IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: My object1 is ofcorse List<MyClass1> and the second parameter is the expected result type. that is how toy use the conversion factory bean..., with the code above i get null returned